# Multiplication of lists of different sizes

Tags: python, list, multiplication

```
import numpy as np

newResidues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newI = [[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0]]
sqrt = 10

templist = []

from itertools import compress

for i in newI:
   valuesofresidues = list(compress(newResidues, i))
   templist = valuesofresidues
   print templist
```

This returns

```
[1, 3, 5]
[1, 2]
[1, 4]
```

Now, let's take the first row, `[1,3,5]` 
I need to do the following operations 
`pow((sqrt + 1),2) + pow((sqrt + 3), 2) + pow((sqrt + 5),2)` and return the sum for all rows separately. So that it returns

```
515
265
317
```

I tried adding a nested for loop

```
for temp in range(n):
    x = templist[temp]
    xsquare = pow(sqrt+x,2)
```

but it's not working the way I need it to.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please replace *"not working the way I need it to"* with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function to get the sum:

```
def getSum(sublist):
    return sum(pow(sqrt+x, 2) for x in sublist)
```

Shell example:

```
>>> for i in newI:
   valuesofresidues = list(compress(newResidues, i))
   templist = valuesofresidues
   getSum(templist)


515.0
265.0
317.0
```